# How do I connect GitHub to Shopify?

Tags: github, version-control, shopify

I've used Beanstalk and Tower in the past for version control, however, is there a way to connect Shopify to GitHub?

Ideally, I'd like to have a copy of my Shopify theme on my desktop to work on, then when I'm ready to push the changes, I'll use the GitHub Desktop app to push to Shopify.

How do I go about connecting Shopify and GitHub together?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to preview your local changes on a Shopify theme you need to push them to the Shopify server and test them on a development store or as an unpublished theme on a live store.

Accordingly, I would recommend using a command line tool like Shopify's slate (https://github.com/Shopify/slate). This will allow you to watch for changes in your local files and push them to your Shopify store. I wrote a post here on setting up a new theme for local dev with slate http://www.codeshopify.com/blog_posts/local-shopify-development-with-slate

In terms of git / github integration you can use this for version control the same way you would any other site.

When it comes time to put your Shopify site live you can simply publish the theme and make sure you have removed the storefront password.

Comment: Cheers!

I ended up using Slate as the theme base, with Shopify connected to Beanstalk and Fork as the git client.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need a Premium Shopify account , but anyways if you have 1 I recommend you to use this : https://zapier.com/zapbook/github/shopify/ !
It explains you step by step on how to do it!